# Placement of `-l' option in gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

I have some trouble with the placement of the `-l` option when using `gcc`. Here's a stripped down version for reproduce the problem.

t.c:

```
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
    pthread_create(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

and in terminal:

```
$ gcc -lpthread t.c  
/tmp/ccmkwV7B.o: In function `main':  
t.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `pthread_create'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc t.c -lpthread  
$ (compiles ok)
```

Why do I have to put `-lpthread` in the end to make it work? And it seems that this problem only occurs on 32bit linux.

My environment info is attached below:
`gcc -lpthread t.c` fails on this machine.

```
$ gcc --version  
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1  

$ uname -rm  
3.0.0-12-generic i686
```

`gcc -lpthread t.c` works on this machine.

```
$ uname -rm  
2.6.18-274.3.1.el5 x86_64  

$ gcc --version  
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
```

---

I looked up the gcc manual, and it says that **"the placement of -l is significant"**. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: This depends the most on the linker. If you could do `ld --version` for both systems, that might be more enlightening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html),

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

This means it is very interesting that linking the library first works on gcc 4.1.2. This might have to do with the default libraries linked to by the compiler. I know on some installations I don't need to explicitly link to pthreads.

On further reflection, I think the issue is with the flag `--as-needed`, which may be on by default in your gcc 4.6 system. See this [link](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/qa/asneeded.xml) for some discussion.