# Undefined reference to `stdscr' while using ncurses

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, ncurses

I am trying to compile my code in Ubuntu 11.10 and getting these errors and more.So far by googling it I think it is a linking error. Specifically, there have been suggestions to make sure you have the right headers and link the -lncurses library. I have already done that. I'm still getting this error. I also read that may be i should install the libncurses, but I already have it installed.

```
My MakeFile:
CPP           = g++
CPPFLAGS      = -c -Wall -g
LINK          = g++
LDFLAGS_LINUX = -lpthread -lncurses
LDFLAGS       = $(LDFLAGS_LINUX)
RM            = rm


.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp

.cpp.o:
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $(SRC_DIR)$*.o

all: skygrid

skygrid: skygrid.o commServer.o pose.o robot.o
    $(LINK) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) -rf *.o skygrid

skygrid.o:  skygrid.cpp definitions.h commServer.h pose.h robot.h
commServer.o:   commServer.cpp commServer.h
pose.o:     pose.cpp pose.h
robot.o:    robot.cpp robot.h pose.h
```

My Errors:

```
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1094: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1094: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1094: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1094: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1104: undefined reference to `werase'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1106: undefined reference to `wprintw'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1107: undefined reference to `wprintw'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1109: undefined reference to `wprintw'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1111: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1111: undefined reference to `wgetch'
/home/fari/Desktop/FarahSkygrid/skygrid/src/skygrid.cpp:1116: undefined reference to `wtouchln'
```

Comment: The convention is to use CPP for the preprocessor, CPPFLAGS as flags for the preprocessor, CXX for the C++ compiler, and CXXFLAGS for flags to CXX.  Assigning CPP as a C++ compiler will mangle make's implicit rules.

Comment: Thanks for all who tried to help. I'm actually no longer working with this code and I don't have access to it either. So, I did not try anything other than what Keith Thompson suggested and that had not worked for me. For other who might be running into the same problem please try the other answers and mark them useful if they are so.

Comment: I was having the same problem and the fix was to use -l at the end: `gcc -o hello hello.c -lncurses`

Answer (score 33):

I was having this problem with an ncurses program on Centos 6.2.  It turns out that ncurses is sometimes split into two libraries, `ncurses` and `tinfo`.  In my case, `stdscr` exists in `libtinfo`, not in libncurses, so adding `-ltinfo` to the link line, after `-lncurses`, solved the problem.

Comment: I was missing just the -lncurses flag. wouldn't have figured it out wo this post :)

Answer (score 5):

I know you've moved on, but for future reference: when I encountered the same problem, it was due to the placement of the -l argument. Try:

```
skygrid: skygrid.o commServer.o pose.o robot.o
    $(LINK) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

For more information, see the gcc manual: 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

and this thread on SO:
[Placement of `-l' option in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612147/placement-of-l-option-in-gcc)

Answer (score 2):

user1246043,

I've been having a similar problem. Basically, I can't compile wiht g++ 4.5 or g++ 4.6, so I installed g++ 4.4 and used that. This specifically solved my problem with linking to ncursesw.

```
# Makefile:
CXX=g++-4.4                                                                  
CXXLIBS=-lncursesw                                                           
CXXFLAGS=-Wall
# Other stuff omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the error messages refer to specific lines in your `skygrid.cpp` source file, they're not linker errors.

You probably need to add

```
#include <curses.h>
```

to the top of that source file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already have #include <ncurses.h> in my file. This code is compiling and already running on other computers with older version of Ubuntu and on a Mac(forgot the exact os),just not on my computer with Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Odd.  I don't have your sources, but I put together a small example on my own Ubuntu 11.04 system, and it works.  https://gist.github.com/1968401

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I will try your example code on my computer when I get a chance and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Hi,
I tried you code and I still got the same undefined reference error.
fari@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$ make
g++ -c -Wall -g skygrid.cpp -o skygrid.o
g++ -lpthread -lncurses -o skygrid skygrid.o
skygrid.o: In function `main':
/home/fari/Desktop/test/skygrid.cpp:4: undefined reference to `stdscr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [skygrid] Error 1
fari@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the same problem when building cscope 15.8.

After `./configure`, I first get error saying "ncurses.h" not found. It's because there is no libncurses-dev installed on my os.

After installing libcurses-dev, I run `make` directly. Then got dozens of the "undefined reference to" error.

After rebuild from start again, these errors were gone.

`./configure`

`make`

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar problem, when use Qt timer and ncurses: timeout macros ruin out Qt code =)
Solution was `"#undef timeout"` after `#include <ncurses.h>` to prevent macros from working. And if in some cases You will need ncurses timeout, you can run `wtimeout(stdscr,delay)` directly.

Comment: I get the same error for some reason. `undefined reference to stdscr; undefined reference to wgetch`

Answer (score 0):

My gcc linking issue solved by using proper ncurses libs & flags
obtained by **ncurses5-config**.

Added to **Makefile** compilation params as **`ncurses5-config --cflags --libs`** and app finally linked.

Use correct ncurses configuration tool version for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue.

I needed to use the "strftime" C function.
It seems that "ncurses" library includes it, in which case can be easily downloaded and installed on modern Linux/Unix distros (I am using FreeBSD 13.1).

I had to then include "curses.h" to the C/C++ file and when compiling I also had to use the ncurses flag: "-lncurses"

This is the command I used for compiling:

```
clang++ -v -g strftime.cpp -o strftime -lncurses
```

I need to use "strftime" with along in C++, worked for me.

Comment: *ncurses* doesn't use `strftime`