# function similar to getchar

Tags: console, go, getchar

Is there a Go function similar to C's `getchar` able to handle tab press in console? I want to make some sort of completion in my console app.

Comment: Found a good example for rolling your own: https://github.com/SimonWaldherr/golang-examples/blob/master/advanced/getchar.go

Answer (score 25, accepted):

C's `getchar()` example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char ch;
    ch = getchar();
    printf("Input Char Is :%c",ch);
}
```

Go equivalent:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    fmt.Printf("Input Char Is : %v", string([]byte(input)[0]))

    // fmt.Printf("You entered: %v", []byte(input))
}
```

The last commented line just shows that when you press `tab` the first element is U+0009 ('CHARACTER TABULATION').

However for your needs (detecting tab) C's `getchar()` is not suitable as it requires the user to hit enter. What you need is something like ncurses' getch()/ readline/ jLine as mentioned by @miku. With these, you actually wait for a single keystroke.

So you have multiple options:

1. Use `ncurses` / `readline` binding, for example https://code.google.com/p/goncurses/ or equivalent like https://github.com/nsf/termbox
2. Roll your own see http://play.golang.org/p/plwBIIYiqG for starting point
3. use `os.Exec` to run stty or jLine.

refs:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/zhBE5MH4n-Q

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/S9AO_kHktiY

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/icMfYF8wJCk

Answer (score 17):

Assuming that you want unbuffered input (without having to hit enter), this does the job on UNIX systems:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // disable input buffering
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "cbreak", "min", "1").Run()
    // do not display entered characters on the screen
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "-echo").Run()
    // restore the echoing state when exiting
    defer exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "echo").Run()

    var b []byte = make([]byte, 1)
    for {
        os.Stdin.Read(b)
        fmt.Println("I got the byte", b, "("+string(b)+")")
    }
}
```

Comment: This leaves the terminal in a non-echoing state after exit. Adding `defer exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "echo")` fixes that.

Comment: defer exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "echo").Run()  doesn't work for me, I have to type 'reset' :(

Comment: Don't do massively inefficient, error prone, non-portable, etc exec of stty when you can just use [`terminal.MakeRaw`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal#MakeRaw) from `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal`.

Comment: If the defer "isn't working", actually build and compile the project to run it, instead of doing go run *.go.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Other answers here suggest such things as:

- Using cgo

  - inefficient
  - ["cgo is not Go"](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/01/18/cgo-is-not-go)
- `os.Exec` of `stty`

  - not portable
  - inefficient
  - error prone
- using code that uses `/dev/tty`

  - not portable
- using a GNU readline package

  - inefficient if it's a wrapper to C readline or if implemented using one of the above techniques
  - otherwise okay

However, for the simple case this is easy just using a package from the [Go Project's Sub-repositories](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1compat#subrepos).

[Edit: Previously this answer used the [`golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal) package which has since been deprecated; it was moved to [`golang.org/x/term`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/term). Code/links updated appropriately.]

Basically, use
[`term.MakeRaw`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/term#MakeRaw) and
[`term.Restore`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/term#Restore)
to set standard input to raw mode (checking for errors, e.g. if stdin is not a terminal); then you can either read bytes directly from `os.Stdin`, or more likely, via a `bufio.Reader` (for better efficiency).

For example, something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/term"
)

func main() {
    // fd 0 is stdin
    state, err := term.MakeRaw(0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("setting stdin to raw:", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := term.Restore(0, state); err != nil {
            log.Println("warning, failed to restore terminal:", err)
        }
    }()

    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        r, _, err := in.ReadRune()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("stdin:", err)
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("read rune %q\r\n", r)
        if r == 'q' {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me.  I only needed to add `"fmt"` to the `import`.

Comment: @RikRenich opps, after testing it I changed the final `log` to `fmt` but didn't adjust the imports. Now fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks goes to Paul Rademacher - this works (at least on Mac):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/pkg/term"
)

func getch() []byte {
    t, _ := term.Open("/dev/tty")
    term.RawMode(t)
    bytes := make([]byte, 3)
    numRead, err := t.Read(bytes)
    t.Restore()
    t.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    return bytes[0:numRead]
}

func main() {
    for {
        c := getch()
        switch {
        case bytes.Equal(c, []byte{3}):
            return
        case bytes.Equal(c, []byte{27, 91, 68}): // left
            fmt.Println("LEFT pressed")
        default:
            fmt.Println("Unknown pressed", c)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly on Linux also

Comment: Using `/dev/tty` is non-portable. *Never* ignore errors! Don't flip the terminal in/out of raw mode for each "character", don't re-open "/dev/tty" for each "character". This doesn't actually get characters but up to three bytes.

Answer (score 1):

1- You may use `C.getch()`:

This works in Windows command line, Reads only one character without Enter:
(Run output binary file inside shell (terminal), not inside pipe or Editor.)

```golang
package main

//#include<conio.h>
import "C"

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := C.getch()
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

2- For Linux ( tested on Ubuntu ):

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
char getch(){
    char ch = 0;
    struct termios old = {0};
    fflush(stdout);
    if( tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0 ) perror("tcsetattr()");
    old.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    old.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    old.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    old.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    if( tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0 ) perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
    if( read(0, &ch,1) < 0 ) perror("read()");
    old.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    old.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    if(tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0) perror("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
    return ch;
}
*/
import "C"

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(C.getch())
    fmt.Println()
}
```

See:
[What is Equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux)
[Why can't I find <conio.h> on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux)

---

3- Also this works, but needs "Enter":

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    c, err := r.ReadByte()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

Comment: Still need to hit enter for me on openSUSE Leap 42.1 . :(

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that `conio.h` is windows only! I have tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541679/undefined-reference-to-stdscr), it's able to run but the getch() always return -1.

Comment: Finally, I take @blinry 's method.

Comment: @lfree: See new Edit for Linux ( 2), I hope this helps.

Comment: The second method works on openSUSE Leap42.1. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: the linux version actually only works with a terminal as stdin, not with a pipe

Comment: When trying to build/run the linux version, it complains: could not determine kind of name for C.getch

Answer (score -5):

You can also use ReadRune:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
// ...
char, _, err := reader.ReadRune()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error reading key...", err)
}
```

A rune is similar to a character, as GoLang does not really have characters, in order to try and support multiple languages/unicode/etc.

Comment: ReadRune reads one character at a time, but it is triggered only when pressing enter in a console; this is why this doesn't solve the OP's issue. (I wondered why you didn't have more upvotes, and just tried it :) )