# Read a character from standard input in Go (without pressing Enter)

Tags: go, stdin

I want my app to show:

```
press any key to exit ...
```

And to exit when I press **any** key.

How can I achieve this?

Note: I have googled but all of what I've found needed to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end. I want something like `Console.ReadKey()` in C#.

I am running MS Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Golang function similar to getchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094190/golang-function-similar-to-getchar)

Comment: @jnml No; this is not a duplicate. I've seen that question before and using the code provided in answer you still need to press enter at stdin.

Comment: The duplicity is solely about the question, not about any answer to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The package "golang.org/x/term" allows you to switch the stdin into raw mode to read each byte at a time.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/term"
)

func main() {
    // switch stdin into 'raw' mode
    oldState, err := term.MakeRaw(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer term.Restore(int(os.Stdin.Fd()), oldState)

    b := make([]byte, 1)
    _, err = os.Stdin.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("the char %q was hit", string(b[0]))
}
```

Answer (score 36):

This is a minimal working example for those running a UNIX system:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // disable input buffering
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "cbreak", "min", "1").Run()
    // do not display entered characters on the screen
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "-echo").Run()

    var b []byte = make([]byte, 1)
    for {
        os.Stdin.Read(b)
        fmt.Println("I got the byte", b, "("+string(b)+")")
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the display the entered characters back on the screen?

Comment: Ibolit: They already get displayed in the example. To display only the characters, `fmt.Print(string(b))` should work.

Comment: lbolit: use `exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "echo").Run()` to get them back.

Answer (score 15):

[termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) is a light-weight Go-native package which offers some rudimentary terminal control. Including the ability to get input in raw mode (read one character at a time without the default line-buffered behaviour).

It also has fairly ok compatibility across different systems.

And [keyboard](https://github.com/jteeuwen/keyboard) extends termbox-go to give some additional keyboard functionality like multi-key shortcuts and sequences.

Comment: That's not what the definition of raw_mode is.

Answer (score 10):

go-termbox is very heavyweight.  It wants to take over the entire terminal window.  For example, it clears the screen on startup, which may not be what you want.

I put this together on OSX.  Just a tiny getchar():

https://github.com/paulrademacher/climenu/blob/master/getchar.go

Comment: works on linux too, but it reads from the terminal, not stdin (which could be a pipe)

Answer (score 10):

You could use this library (mine): https://github.com/eiannone/keyboard

This is an example for getting a single keystroke:

```
char, _, err := keyboard.GetSingleKey()
if (err != nil) {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("You pressed: %q\r\n", char)
```

Comment: great library. At least for windows, this solution is much better and to the point than others.

Answer (score 2):

You can read a single key-press from a terminal in raw mode. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/ssh/terminal/util.go?repo=crypto) is a package that should provide raw terminal mode to your program. Catch: it's Linux only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - http://play.golang.org/p/kg-QirlucY.

Just read from the `os.Stdin` at the end of the `func main`

Comment: This code demonstrates how to use `SetConsoleMode`. If want "Press Enter to continue", then `os.Stdin.Read([]byte{0})` is enough.