# Scanning for up and down arrow in Go?

Tags: go, stdin, scanf, keycode

I'm trying to scan for the up and down arrow key codes in Go, but it doesn't seem to be working. So far I've tried this:

```
in = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
b, err := in.ReadByte()
fmt.Println("Key code:", b, err)
```

But when I press the up or down key, it never stops reading (it never run the `Println` statement) and just displays "^[[A" and "^[[B" directly in the terminal. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you can't get raw mode input easily without os syscalls. Have a look at the answers to [Read a character from standard input in Go (without pressing Enter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159118/read-a-character-from-standard-input-in-go-without-pressing-enter) .

It seems that the generally accepted solution is to use [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) which apparently has fairly good cross platform capability.

Comment: In addition, you also might want to compare termbox-go with tcell, which takes a different design approach in some areas. https://github.com/gdamore/tcell It might be better or worse, depending on your needs.