# Can not run bash `read` command from Golang

Tags: go, exec, stdin

I tried to use a basic bash command `read` to capture a single character from a keyboard. But it seemed difficult to get the output even I try several ways.

Sample code:

```
fmt.Println(exec.Command("read", "-t", "5", "-n", "1").Output())
```

Its meaning is "waiting for 5 seconds to get 1 input character from the keyboard". From code above I expected to see my input character printed out together with its error but what do I get is

Output:

```
[] exit status 1
```

This output is just immediately printed in lesser than 1 second which conflicts to `"-t", "5"` argument of `read` command which stands for waiting for 5 second. I try to type some character within 1 second but it seems doesn't work at all.

BTW, if try this

```
fmt.Println(exec.Command("echo", "\"Hi!\"").Output())
```

output:

```
[34 104 105 34 10] <nil>
```

It seems work here with simple `echo` here.

Comment: Read is a bash command, not an executable in your PATH like echo. Maybe invoking read inside bash could work. I'd suggest to find a Go-only solution.

Comment: @Volker I just want to capture `spacebar` that's all. Do you have any suggestion for a simple go-only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not providing the command with stdin, so there's nothing it can read and it exits immediately.

If you want to hook it up the same stdin as the calling program, you can use:

```
cmd := exec.Command("read", "-t", "5", "-n", "1")
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

fmt.Println("error:", err)
fmt.Printf("output: %q\n", out)
```

This however won't output anything, since the `/usr/bin/read` script isn't going to print anything. You probably want the shell builtin `read` to be called in the context of a shell. This would print the character read:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "read -t 5 -n 1 C && echo -n $C")
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
```

But in the end, you should probably just read directly from stdin in go.

Comment: Thank for your answer @JimB. I've tried your code, it's sound good, but I got "" from `out` every times I input.

Comment: @terces907: that's because `read` isn't printing any output. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to get a given input character.

Comment: @terces907: I added some more info. Why not just do it in Go?

Comment: I just want to capture `spacebar` which input from keyboard without entering from user. For sure, it can be done by code you've given me above. Any simpler way for golang-only code please suggest @JimB.

Comment: @terces907: bash puts the tty in raw mode for `read`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159118/read-a-character-from-standard-input-in-go-without-pressing-enter, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094190/golang-function-similar-to-getchar