# How to read a char with Golang in Windows without requiring return key?

Tags: windows, go, io, getchar

In my Go program which I run on **MS Windows** I want to get a confirmation for a 'delete file' action with the keys y/n/a, and it's going to be repeated a big number of times. And I do not want to have to press enter for each time.

I've tried answers from  [Read a character from standard input in Go (without pressing Enter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159118/read-a-character-from-standard-input-in-go-without-pressing-enter) without success.

1. Answer based on `exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "cbreak", "min", "1").Run()`
   It is for UNIX
2. Answer based on termbox-go , it is a bit overkill for what I need, just to read a char. I did not had the time to learn and use termbox-go
3. getchar.go
   It is for OSX
4. https://github.com/eiannone/keyboard
   It hangs and does not read the keystroke
5. golang.org/x/term
   `term.MakeRaw(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))` gives the error `The handle is invalid`
6. Next answer it is only for Linux
7. The last answer does not show how to read a char

Any proposal for Windows? I find it a bit remarkable that Golang does not have a built-in method similar to `getChar()`, or at least in the packages `io` or `bufio`, e.g., readRune or readByte still require `Enter`, even when you're supposed to only read one of them.

Comment: No reply yet? I've the same question. I must accept a single char and go one without pressing Enter

Comment: No, I gave up... I do not know if there are new libraries or updates that give a solution.