# How to pause a program?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, go

I want to realize the `pause` function like windows shell command `pause`. For example,

```
$ go run script.go 
Any key to continue...     //Then any key to continue
```

On windows, we can use the system command by golang function `exec.Command()`. But how about on Linux? I want to use the command `read -n1 -p "Any key to continue"` as a compromised one, but it doesn't work in the function `exec.Command("read", "-n", "1")`. I tested a lot but failed to know why.

Besides, do anyone know how to achieve the pause function just by golang language itself without using the external command?

Comment: [Read a line and discard it](http://golang-examples.tumblr.com/post/41863665491/read-a-line-from-stdin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just read from stdin. The user would have to press enter for you program to continue. Or set the terminal into "raw" mode. For the later case, there's eg. [nsf's termbox](http://godoc.org/github.com/nsf/termbox-go)

Comment: Yes, I know readline from stdin can work. But that needs the user input a `Enter` key. I want to know if we can enter any key without the `Enter` key to realize the `pause` command.

Comment: @wenlibin02: Have you actually read my answer? It _is_ there ;-)

Comment: I am sorry that I did not understand it at first, Though I still don't know it now. Here is another realization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17278730/2507321, it works well!

Answer (score 6):

Read a line from the standard input, then discard it ([source](http://golang-examples.tumblr.com/post/41863665491/read-a-line-from-stdin)):

```
bio := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
line, hasMoreInLine, err := bio.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure if you can do that if you do not disable except you uncook then terminal (disable input buffering)> here is a [simple solution](https://github.com/droundy/iolaus/blob/master/src/util/cook.go) to that

This is OS dependent to better ask the user the press enter. You also want to capture signals such as `Ctrl+Z` or `Ctrl+C` etc.

```
c := make(chan os.Signal)
d := make(chan bool)

// Capture Control
signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)

//Capture Enter
go func() {
    bio := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    bio.ReadByte()
    d <- true
}()


fmt.Println("Any key to continue... ")

// Block
select {
    case <- d :
    case <- c :
}

fmt.Println("Mission Completed")
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found the following methods:

In Linux Shell Script:

```
echo -ne "press any key to continue..."; stty -echo; read -n1; stty echo
```

In Golang for Linux (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278730/2507321):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // disable input buffering
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "cbreak", "min", "1").Run()
    // do not display entered characters on the screen
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "-echo").Run()

    var b []byte = make([]byte, 1)

    fmt.Printf("any key to continue...")
    os.Stdin.Read(b)
}
```

In Golang for windows:

```
exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "pause")
```