# Insert slice into url link as text

Tags: go

I am trying to make a bot which sends mails. I got the following code. I am wondering, if it's possible to place the `mails` slice into this field seperated by a `,` ?

`&bcc=`

If my test.txt contains

```
test1@mail.com
test2@mail.com
```

I'd like the part of the link to contain `&bcc=test1@mail.com,test2@mail.com`
Is this doable with Go?

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var mails []string

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        mails = append(mails, scanner.Text())
    }

    fmt.Println(mails)
    exec.Command("xdg-open", "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?fs=1&tf=cm&to=contact@test.com,&bcc=test1@mail.com,test2@mail.com&su=Hello+World!&body=This+Is+Just+An+Example").Run()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "fmt.Sprintf()".It solves your problem.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var mails []string

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        mails = append(mails, scanner.Text())
    }

    sendMails := ""
    for _, m := range mails {
        sendMails += fmt.Sprintf("%s", m)
    }
    command := fmt.Sprintf("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?fs=1&tf=cm&to=contact@test.com,&bcc=%s&su=Hello+World!&body=This+Is+Just+An+Example", sendMails)
    fmt.Println(mails)
    exec.Command("xdg-open", command).Run()

}
```

Comment: it is in the answer.

Comment: I have one more question, is it possible to stimulate keyboard click with Go?

Comment: @FriedRiceEaterz maybe check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198193/how-to-react-to-keypress-events-in-go). If you are trying to press a key in order to send an email or perform some action (I see the mail.google.com link in your initial code), maybe you should use the Gmail API instead.