# How do I have in Go what Console.ReadKey() does in .NET?

Tags: go, console

anyone have any idea how I should do Console.ReadKey() method in Golang?
I want it to just return a key as soon as it is pressed, without waiting for Enter.

Comment: Possibly duplicate question, have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094190/function-similar-to-getchar

Comment: Please read the help section, specifically on how to write a good question: include a clear description of the problem, code to reproduce, and _show us what you've tried_.

Comment: This still waits for enter

Comment: This question, if to be answered as stated, requires an answer the size of 3-4 printed pages. Do you need it cross-platform or are you targetting some specific OS? Answering partially, Go's standard library has no direct support for what you're after.

Comment: @ibrahim-dogan, close but not 100%: you can have `getchar(3)` in Go by merely calling `Read()` on `os.Stdin` passing it a one-byte slice, but on POSIX systems it won't behave quite like `Console.ReadKey()`.

Comment: Take a look to golang tcell library. It provides text terminal operations. Example reading a key: https://github.com/gdamore/tcell/blob/master/_demos/hello_world.go#L78