# Error during the compilation of a code C++

Tags: c++

I have got a problem with my code c++ when i assay to compile it.
     ^

This is the complete code ,the error line is just down includes

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

const char KEY_LEFT = 'a', KEY_RIGHT = 'd',KEY_UP = 'w', KEY_DOWN ='s'; 
const int HEIGHT = 25, WIDTH = 40;
bool  hasntWon = true; 
int hP = 100; 
//unsigned char  healthbar [10] = {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'};

enum  DirectionX {Right,Left};
enum  DirectionY {Up,Down};

struct Player {
  char sprite;
  int x;
  int y; 
 };

 struct Enemy{
  char sprite;
  int x;
  int y; 
  DirectionX pastDirX; 
  DirectionY pastDirY; 
 };
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the file that is not compiling. Remember to indent lines with four spaces to format correctly.

Comment: No Posted Code == No Help.

Comment: Remember, edit your post with **text**, no screen snapshots of the code.  Screen snapshots don't paste well into IDEs.

Comment: Try using `char` for characters, not integers.

Comment: i post the code but it doesn't respect formattinf of c++

Comment: is `KEY_LEFT` defined as a macro somewhere?

Comment: same error when i using char

Comment: yes hlt. In #include <ncurses.h>

Comment: I did not see `#include <ncurses.h>` in your question's code.  Try using identifiers that do not collide with macros.

Comment: Are you trying to redefine a macro in NCurses?

Comment: *Always* post the complete text of the error message (verbatim and *in* the question) when there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments you are including `ncurses.h`, which contains

```
#define KEY_LEFT 0404 /* left-arrow key */
```

That is a macro, which will automatically be substituted by the preprocessor, turning your code into

```
const int 0404 = 'a' /* ... */;
```

`0404` is not a valid variable name, so your code does not compile. In general, you could try to redefine these macros (via `#define`). However,  redefining them may cause havoc in other places.

If you are trying to treat <kbd>a</kbd> just like <kbd>←</kbd>, I would recommand checking for the appropriate key instead of (or alongside to) `KEY_LEFT` in whatever place you use that macro.

Comment: OK. Please , what should i put in the place of  KEY_LEFT = 'a'

Comment: i edit ncurses.h like that :    #define KEY_DOWN bas//0402  /* down-arrow key */
#define KEY_UP  haut//0403  /* up-arrow key */
#define KEY_LEFT gauche//0404  /* left-arrow key */
#define KEY_RIGHT droit//0405  /* right-arrow key */      And i have go this error when i compile                                        /tmp/cc11Y2oC.o : Dans la fonction « main » :
mazegame.cpp:(.text+0x8a3) : référence indéfinie vers « stdscr »
mazegame.cpp:(.text+0x8ab) : référence indéfinie vers « wgetch »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @fogang fokoa - ehh, don't edit ncurses. Just use a different name for your own variable(s).

Comment: OK. i reedit ncurses.h, it's okay.  During the compilation, i get this error :     mazegame.cpp:(.text+0x8a3) : référence indéfinie vers « stdscr »
mazegame.cpp:(.text+0x8ab) : référence indéfinie vers « wgetch »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need to compile with `-lncurses`. If it still can't find `stdscr`, [add `-ltinfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541679/undefined-reference-to-stdscr)