# ncurses compiling: 'stdscr'/lib64/libtinfo.so.6: error adding symbol

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to compile anything using `ncurses` and I have some sort of linking error. Why? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    printw("Hello World!!");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}

lore% gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c  -lncurses
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/cc37p6Qp.o: un
defined reference to symbol 'stdscr' /lib64/libtinfo.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's great that you solved your problem! Now to make your question even more useful to other people, please consider making that comment into an answer. Yes, you can answer your own questions! And tomorrow you'll be able to accept your own answer, for even more kudos. (Of course, someone else might come up with an even better answer, so you'd be able to choose which one to accept. But it's all good.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found Answer: [undefined reference to `stdscr'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541679/undefined-reference-to-stdscr)

I was having this problem with an ncurses program on Centos 6.2. It turns out that ncurses is sometimes split into two libraries, *ncurses* and *tinfo*. In my case, `stdscr` exists in `libtinfo`, not in `libncurses`, so adding `-ltinfo` to the link line, after `-lncurses`, solved the problem.

Comment: Note, you can add markdown formatting to make the answer read a bit better placing a single `'*'` before and after text to have the text show in *italics* and double `"**"` before and after for **bold**. You can place backtics around text to format as `code` in `monospace` type.

Comment: You should edit your *question* to contain the details, i.e. the operating system and so forth.