# Can't compile correctly throw makefile: [...]: undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'

Tags: c, makefile, undefined-reference, curses

I was trying to compile a file via `make`. The file is not mine, and I don't totally understand it, but I have to compile it. I know I'm using curses, and I am on Windows.

This is the makefile:

```
CFLAG = -Wall -pedantic -Wno-comment -O3 -std=c89
  
all: pong pong_log

game.o: game.h game.c
    gcc $(CFLAG) -c game.c

display.o: display.h display.c
    gcc $(CFLAG) -c display.c

pong: game.h display.h game.o display.o main.c
    gcc $(CFLAG) display.o game.o main.c -o pong -lncurses

pong_log: game.h display.h game.o display.o main.c
    gcc $(CFLAG) -D REG display.o game.o main.c -o pong_log -lncurses 

clean:
    rm -rf *.o pong pong_log
```

And the error I get is:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -Wno-comment -O3 -std=c89 display.o game.o main.c -o pong -lncurses
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: display.o:display.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: display.o:display.c:(.text+0x302): undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: display.o:display.c:(.text+0xbb8): undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: display.o:display.c:(.text+0xc85): undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: display.o:display.c:(.text+0xcb3): undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:12: pong] Error 1
```

Comment: Try adding `-ltinfo` when linking with ncurses: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11269810/6121044

Comment: As you have presented it, your makefile is a bit mangled.  At minimum, some line breaks have been removed.  I presume that that happened in the process of posting the code here, because the diagnostic messages presented are not consistent with the makefile in the form given.

Comment: @JohnBollinger now is correct

Comment: @Andreas I am not so good with C, so i triend to ad -ltinfo at the end of the line, but it seys that it cannot find it